# Output behavior while Defining Bit field in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct value
    {
        int bit1:1;
        int bit2:4;
        int bit3:4;
    } bit;

    printf ("%d\n", sizeof(bit));
    return 0;
}
```

Output on Tc/Tc++:

> 2

Output under Linux:

> 4

I know I am missing some concept of bit fields.

Comment: What were you expecting it to be?

Comment: @kevin in my understanding in gcc int consider as 2 byte while on linux it is considering as 4byte that's why it is producing different result.correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Nishant: You're almost correct. Tc/Tc++ has a 2-byte `int` and GCC on Linux has a 4-byte `int`. Tc/Tc++ is just ***that*** old...

Comment: So you're expecting 2 bytes because the 9 bits fit into a single int?  Ints are 4 bytes in gcc, but gcc and the iso standard make no guarantees about the size of a struct, with or without the bitfields, anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of the given structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025934/size-of-the-given-structure)

Comment: @Kevin: Actually, I wasn't expecting any specific number since I do realize that it's implementation dependent. I should have added the word "apparently" into my last comment. But I can't edit it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof` for the struct is not the same as the sum of the sizes of all the elements - this is especially the case with bitfields.

Typically, the struct needs to be padded to a certain size and alignment. (Which apparently is 2 on Tc/Tc++ and 4 in Linux.)

So although there's only 9 bits in use, it's being padded out to the word-size.

**EDIT :**

Note that the C standard does not specify how much padding is done. And therefore, you are getting different results from two different compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure size is rounded up to machine word. Think about it - how else can it be stored (and addressed) in memory or in a register?

Comment: And elements of it can also be word-aligned making the total even larger.