# How can I have exactly 2 bits in memory?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bitset, memory-efficient

I should be able to store a value in a data structure that could go from 0 to 3.. so I need 2 bits. This data structure I will be great  2 ^ 16 locations. So, i want to have 2 ^ 16 * 2 (bits). In C + + do you use to have exactly 2 bits in memory?

Comment: If your values go from 0 to 3 then you need 2 bits...

Comment: I am surprised that such a simple question go here... It seems that some people forgot the good habits of reading entire books on a new subject....

Comment: @Basile: C++ is a special case that most people aren't prepared for. It does not have an intuitive interface. Almost all of my university career, up to my Master's degree in mathematics, I understood without reading a book (in fact I read one book, for one course that I hadn't properly followed the first time). C++, I had to buy a book.

Comment: It should depend upon countries... In France, you need to read books after high-school to follow courses ... And I don't claim people should *buy* books, I just think they should *read* books (perhaps in university library, borrowed from a friend, ...). But I agree with you that C++ is not happy to learn (Ocaml is much sexier).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need two bits per unit (not three), so you can pack four units into one byte, or 16 units into one 32-bit integer.

So you will need a `std::array<uint32_t, 4096>` to accomodate 2<sup>16</sup> units of 2-bit values.

You access the *n*<sup>th</sup> value as follows:

```
unsigned int get(std::size_t n, std::array<uint32_t, 4096> const & arr)
{
    const uint32_t u = arr[n / 16];
    return (u >> (2 * (n % 16))) & 0x3;
}
```

Alternatively, you could go with a bitfield:

```
struct BF32 {
  uint32_t u0 : 2;
  uint32_t u1 : 2;
  //...
  uint32_t uF : 2;
}
```

And then make an `std::array<BF32, 4096>`.

Comment: Be aware that even a bitfield that takes fewer than `n` bits (where `n` is the number of bits in a byte) will be padded.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I think I'm being aware... I'm using the guaranteed-width `uint32_t` type; is that not sufficiently well-defined?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot allocate a single object that is less than 1 byte (because 1 byte is the smallest addressable unit in the system).

You can, however, have portions of a structure that are smaller than a byte using bitfields.  You could create one of these to hold 8 of your values, the size of this is exactly 3 bytes:

```
#pragma pack(1) // MSVC requires this
struct three_by_eight {
  unsigned value1 : 3;
  unsigned value2 : 3;
  unsigned value3 : 3;
  unsigned value4 : 3;
  unsigned value5 : 3;
  unsigned value6 : 3;
  unsigned value7 : 3;
  unsigned value8 : 3;
}
__attribute__ ((packed)) // GCC requires this
;
```

These can be clumsy to work with since they can't be accessed using `[]`....  Your best be would be to create your own class that works similar to a `bitset` but works on 3 bits instead of 1.

Comment: gcc will make this struct 4 bytes long.  Also, it warns about it being a gnu extension, just use `unsigned int` (why `char` anyway? With bitfields it's all the same length).  Use 2-bit fields like the OP actually needs and 16 of them.

Comment: added explicit packing directives

Comment: OK, but it would probably be faster if they were word-aligned.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @SoapBox: You should probably be using unsigned types for bitfields (ie replace `int` by `unsigned`).

Comment: @Kevin if he wanted fast he;d just use a char for each one, I assume he wants them small for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not working on an embedded system and resources are sufficient, you can have a look at [`std::bitset<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) which will make your job as a programmer easier.

But if you are working on an embedded system, the bitset is probably not good for you (your compiler probably doesn't even support templates). There are a number of techniques for manipulating bits, each with its own quirks; here's an article that might help you:
> http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/avr_3_04.pdf

Answer (score 0):

0 to 3 has 4 possible values. Since log2(4) == 2, or because 2^2 == 4, you need two bits, no three.

You might want to use [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)

Comment: If you mean bit-fields as defined by the C/C++ languages, then no, you probably don't want to use them for this.

Comment: I almost never use bit fields, but GGSalent seems to ask for them. Still, I can't understand why he ask such a question... Reading any good C programming book will help him much more (than asking dumb questions like this here), and more importantly he will learn more....

Comment: It seems that he wants to use exactly 3 bits in memory which is impossible. You could abstract that fact away but it doesn't mean you are suddenly having 3 bit bytes in memory.

Comment: I depends how you understand those 2 or 3 bits. If for whatever reason he wants to represent a thousand of such 3 bits chunks, he could manage to consume less than a byte for each chunk (with e.g. tricks like bit fields or bit manipulation on words like `unsigned int`). Still I am very surprised of the question.

Comment: I probably I expressed myself badly ... I know that you can't allocate 2 bits but the minimum is 8 ... I just wanted to know if you think there's a clever way to exploit those 6 bits (8-2) more ...
Basile Starynkevitch .... tries to be less arrogant ... thanks

Comment: Read a good C programming book. Unless you have millions of 2 bits chunk, today (with even small machines having half a gigabyte of memory), you don't care about individual bits (keep in mind that accessing bits is much slower than working on bytes or words).

Answer (score 0):

There was a [discussion on the size allocated to bit-field structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276523/output-behavior-while-defining-bit-field-in-c) last night.  A struct cannot be smaller than a byte, and with most machines and compilers will be either 2 or 4, depending on the compiler and word size.  So, no, you can't get a 3-bit struct (2-bit as you actually need).  You can, however, pack bits yourself into an array of, say, `uint64_t`s.  Or you could make a struct with 16 2-bit members and see if gcc makes that a 4-byte struct, then use an array of those.

Answer (score -1):

There a very old trick to sneak a couple of bits around if you already have some data structures. This is quite nasty and unless you have extremely good reasons, it is most likely not at all a good idea. I'm just pointing this out in case you really really need to save a couple of bits.

Due to alignment, pointers on x86 or x64 are often multiples of 4, hence the two least significant bits of such pointers (e.g. pointers to `int`) are always `0`. You can exploit this and sneak your two bits in there, but you have to make sure to remove them, when accessing those pointers (depending on the architecture, I'm not sure here).

Again, this is nasty, dangerous and pretty UB but perhaps it is worth it in your case.

Comment: @Downvoter: It is generally considered polite to leave a comment, explaining the down vote.

Answer (score -2):

```
3^5 = 243
```

and can fit 5 entries in 8bits. You  spend like 20% less space storing lot of data this way. All you need is lookup table for 2 directional lookups and manipulations.

Comment: In 8 bits you can store 5 tristate values, because 3^5 <= 2^8.