# How to create a data type of a given size

Tags: c, variables, struct

I would like to create a struct of size 508 bytes.

Viewing this code I inferred I could create a struct of any size I want.

```
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Common Data Types 
 *
 * The data types in this section are essentially aliases for C/C++ 
 * primitive data types.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309(PROT.10).aspx.
 * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h for more on stdint.h.
 */
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

/**
 * BITMAPFILEHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure contains information about the type, size,
 * and layout of a file that contains a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(VS.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct 
{ 
    WORD   bfType; 
    DWORD  bfSize;  
    WORD   bfReserved1; 
    WORD   bfReserved2; 
    DWORD  bfOffBits; 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) 
BITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

I need type int of size 508 bytes, and after I read this post: [Size of the given structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025934/size-of-the-given-structure) I imagined I could create the int of the size I need. So I tried to create a struct like so:

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    int datachunk : 4064; 
}  
BLOCK;
```

Of course, that is wild imagination and I am wrong.

So, how can I create a struct of size 508 bytes that contains a data type integer of the same size (i.e. 4064?

Comment: There are no built-in integers that large in any implementation that I am aware of.  If you really need a 4064 bit integer, you'll have to use some big-integer implementation, which effectively creates a single big integer out of multiple smaller integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

```
typedef unsigned char fivehundred_and_eight_bytes[508];
```

Comment: the fact that you defined it as char won't affect the outcome? (e.g. the typedef of the code I quoted at the beginning of my question defines the data types as unsigned and signed integers right?)

Comment: @IberoMedia What "outcome"? The only thing you need to pay attention to is `CHAR_BIT` (it might not always be 8). But this code always defines for you a data type which is 508 bytes long.

Comment: OK, I get it. By outcome I meant, and of course the question does include that later I intent to use this data type to read in binary data, and so I imagine I need the type to be integer. But again, I get the size part of it, and the concept. Thank you

Comment: @IberoMedia `char` is really just a `very short int`.

Answer (score 1):

A bit-field can't be wider than an int.

> 6.7.2.1.3 The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant expression with a nonnegative value that does
>   not exceed the width of an object of the type that would be specified
>   were the colon and expression omitted. If the value is zero, the
>   declaration shall have no declarator.